# Examples for successful real life mobile cross-platform / hybrid apps?

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, sample, hybrid

I have nothing found here or on google.

Do you know any (good/successful/most sold/most downloaded) samples for mobile cross-platform apps?
If so, on which frameworks (jQuery Mobile, Sensa, PhoneGap, etc.) are they built on?

I want to get some feeling for wether it is possible to create successful mobile cross-platform apps or not.

Comment: This might be of your interest: [A year using Ionic to build hybrid applications](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/posts/a-year-using-ionic-to-build-hybrid-applications)

Comment: Also: [Meteor and Famo.us on mobile: why JavaScript will win over native](http://info.meteor.com/blog/meteor-famous-mobile)

Answer (score 4):

The success of your application doesn't depend on the platform or framework :))

First, you have to decide whether you want develop a game/social/finance app because games are usually implemented per-platform, but it isn't a rule since appMobi GameDev XDK can be used to create cross-platform games.

appMobi app gallery: http://www.appmobi.com/index.php?q=content/built-appmobi

PhoneGap app gallery: http://phonegap.com/apps

Sencha Demo apps: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/demos/

Appcelerator apps: http://www.appcelerator.com/thinkmobile/showcase

I recommend you to find out what kind of app you want to develop. Later, you can evaluate the platforms/frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

LinkedIN Engineering has published a series of fantastic case studies on their experiences and findings while developing a Hybrid mobile app for iPad :-

http://engineering.linkedin.com/mobile/linkedin-ipad-nativeweb-messaging-bridge-and-websockets

Please refer to another thread i have started on this same topic :-

[Are there any Case Studies similar to the ones published by LinkedIn Engineering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815740/are-there-any-case-studies-similar-to-the-ones-published-by-linkedln-engineering)

Answer (score 0):

QtWebkit you can use html and native code. Famous apps have used this approach.