# Are there any Case Studies similar to the ones published by LinkedIn Engineering?

Tags: html, mobile, hybrid

LinkedIN Engineering has published a series of fantastic case studies on their experiences and findings while developing a Hybrid mobile app for iPad :-

http://engineering.linkedin.com/mobile/linkedin-ipad-nativeweb-messaging-bridge-and-websockets

These articles enable a Mobile Web or Hybrid app developer to get an insight into the real world issues and design options for such apps. I am looking for more such case studies from enterprise mobile app development teams. Any pointers would be welcome.
(There are case studies from specific Framework vendors, but these naturally focus the strengths of their own proprietory solutions. Also the articles from HTML5Rocks.com or GoogleIO do not generally talk about real world apps)

Comment: It's LinkedIn, not LinkedLn ;) It'd be nice for others if you include links to the resources of the case studies. I did a quick search, and found http://venturebeat.com/2012/05/02/linkedin-ipad-app-engineering/#s:1-linkedin-ipad.

Answer (score 3):

Well , you can take a look at the [Evernote Tech Blog](http://blog.evernote.com/tech/page/2/) where they're talking about all the technical stuff and how they do mostly everything. You can find the architecture of the Evernote app and things like that. It's not as great as the LinkedIn one but it's still usefull because they share all the issues they encounter in their development process and give solutions to them.

Hope my answer will help!